# Gauge boson self-interaction diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, feynman-diagrams, yang-mills, self-energy

On page 522 of Peskin and Schroeder, we try to calculate the self-energy of gauge boson. Figure 16.7 gives the following diagrams:

[image]

However, Peskin and Schroeder says there are three additional tadpole diagrams that automatically vanish by [Furry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry%27s_theorem). What are those three additional diagrams?

Edit: are these what Peskin and Schroeder means?

[image]

Comment: The three tadpoles are: a tadpole for the fermions, another one for the ghosts, and a last one for the gauge field itself. Once you know how to draw a tadpole, you can draw them all.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I edited my post, do you mean the diagrams I just drew?

Comment: A tadpole diagram is a diagram with one external leg (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tadpole_(physics))